# Object clone does not work as expected

Tags: apex, clone, bug

I have an object (not SObject!) with a member of type List, when I clone the object and add something to the list, the original record will also be modified:

```
public class ThingToClone {
    public List<Integer> values = new List<Integer>();    
}

ThingToClone original = new ThingToClone();
ThingToClone clone = original.clone();
clone.values.add(1);

System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, original);
```

results in

> 12:04:15:022 USER_DEBUG [5]|ERROR|ThingToClone:[values=(1)]

This is not what I expected, and I was not able to find any "Apex Object" documentation. Is there something like that? All I found was SObject related.

### **Edit:**

To see if it creates a **shadow object**, I also tried to modify a class member, that was not part of the list. called it *Integer anyNumber*

```
ThingToClone original = new ThingToClone();
ThingToClone clone = original.clone();
clone.values.add(1);
clone.anyNumber = 2;
original.anyNumber = 3;
```

The new debug result is something really strange:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, clone);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, original);

USER_DEBUG [6]|ERROR|ThingToClone:[anyNumber=2, values=(1)]
USER_DEBUG [7]|ERROR|ThingToClone:[anyNumber=3, values=(1)]
```

So it's clearly **not** the same(**shadow**) object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree and say it works as expected. My assumption is that Apex `clone()` uses Java's `clone()` internally. Java's `clone()` is a shallow clone, meaning the list in `ThingToClone` will just point to the original objects list.

As described here (http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/#deep_cloning):

> By default, java cloning is ‘field by field copy’ i.e. as the Object
>   class does not have idea about the structure of class on which clone()
>   method will be invoked. So, JVM when called for cloning, do following
>   things:
>
> 1) If the class has only primitive data type members then a completely
>   new copy of the object will be created and the reference to the new
>   object copy will be returned.
>
> 2) If the class contains members of any class type then only the
>   object references to those members are copied and hence the member
>   references in both the original object as well as the cloned object
>   refer to the same object.

So I guess @IllusiveBrain is right in his comment, where he states that `clone()` **copies primitive variables by value** and **non-primitive variables by reference**. 
I'd expect this to be NO platform bug but intended behavior.

Answer (score 5):

***Initially***, I thought that `clone()` creates **shallow** copy of the `Original` and a **pointer** to the original one.

I tried the following to support my argument

```
public class ThingToClone {
    public List<Integer> values = new List<Integer>();    
}

ThingToClone original = new ThingToClone();
ThingToClone clone = original.clone();
ThingToClone clone_of_clone = clone.clone();
clone.values.add(1);
original.values.add(2);

System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Original Instance:' + original);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Clone of  Original:' +clone);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Clone of clone :' + clone_of_clone);
```

**Debug log** proves all ***cloned*** object instances of **wrapper** class,  have the same values

**Debug log**

```
06:17:02.1 (4199907)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|ERROR|Original Instance:ThingToClone:[values=(1, 2)]
06:17:02.1 (4310866)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|ERROR|Clone of  Original:ThingToClone:[values=(1, 2)]
06:17:02.1 (4410739)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|ERROR|Clone of clone :ThingToClone:[values=(1, 2)]
```

A similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11352/cloning-a-wrapper-object-in-apex) is also present on SFSE, that might help you investigate further.

### EDIT

With the recent *turn of events*, I played around a bit and found workaround to your problem.

> **Updated code**

```
public class ThingToClone {
    public List<Integer> values;    
    public integer testInt;
    public Account acc;
}

ThingToClone original = new ThingToClone();
ThingToClone clone = original.clone();
ThingToClone clone_of_clone = clone.clone();

// integer member
original.testInt = 20;
clone.testInt = 2;

// sobject member
Account testAcc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
clone.acc = testAcc;

// collection member
clone.values = new List<integer>();
clone.values.add(1);
original.values = new List<integer>();
original.values.add(2);

System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Original Instance:' + original);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Clone of  Original:' +clone);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Clone of clone :' + clone_of_clone);
```

> **Updated debug log**

```
07:19:35.1 (4421596)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|ERROR|Original Instance:ThingToClone:[acc=null, testInt=20, values=(2)]
07:19:35.1 (4743354)|USER_DEBUG|[23]|ERROR|Clone of Original:ThingToClone:[acc=Account:{Name=Test Account}, testInt=2, values=(1)]
07:19:35.1 (4864965)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|ERROR|Clone of clone :ThingToClone:[acc=null, testInt=null, values=null]
```

> **Explanation**

If I don't create the instance of the `List<>` in the wrapper class, instead create them after **cloning** the object, then the **Values** are preserved. I know, that other member types are getting expected response, but this is just a workaround that I found to get you on the **move**, if you are stuck.

Comment: [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp5IAAS)

Comment: This is not quite true. I also tried it with a member of type Integer and it is not affected.
clone.anyNumber = 2; will still return the initial 1.

Comment: Did you mean, "Integer was a member of the wrapper class"?

Comment: yes, I will update my question, so you can see what I mean, give me a sec

Comment: @Mahmood updated it, thanks for your help, but it prooves, that it is more like a bug and less something like a shadow object.

Comment: Interesting, isn't it? :)
Seems like you have found a bug.

Comment: @Mahmood Yes.. I guess Basti has found a bug.

Comment: I tagged SalesforceSupport on twitter, let's see where this goes. Thanks for contributing guys!

Comment: @Basti: I think I have some new update for you. ;-)
Check my updated answer, plz.

Comment: @Mahmood It works in my case, thank you so much! that saved me a couple hours and keeps my code clean, thank you! I will accept the answer, might be the best solution so far.

Comment: @Mahmood Actually it's more like a Stack and Heap memory parts. Variables which are allocated using Heap are stored in Heap memory and that is why their references are not getting changed unless we manually allocate new memory in Heap and assigned it to the cloned object. Whereas Stack part is getting deep cloned and behaving as expected.

Comment: I must be missing something, what exactly is being called a bug here?  Primitives are value types, collections and classes are reference types, you would not expect `integer i = 0; integer z = i; z = 5;` to end up with `i` equal to `5`, but you would expect `List<Integer> i = new list<integer>(); List<Integer> z = i; z.add(5)` to modify the one `list` being referenced by both variables, since you are assigning a reference to both variables.  Alternatively, try using primitives vs. collections as method parameters, you'll see the same behavior.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian you're missing the fact, that it's not about setting a value = i; it's about setting a value = i.clone();

Comment: @Basti Right, and `i.clone()` effectively calls `newObj.fieldA = oldObj.FieldA` on each member field in the object.  I do see now that you were asking about the initialization of the list effectively being overwritten by the cloned object, I still don't think that's a bug since I would expect clone to do something like `ThingToClone newObj = new ThingToClone(); newObj.values = this.values;`.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian got your point, didn't know this is what clone does, but it explains why it behaves like this and why the workaround works just fine. Thanks for clarifying! You also triggered Robert to write another answer, I asked him to extend it with your knowledge. thanks!