# access all objects associated with related list a particular object in salesforce programatically

Tags: community

I am pretty new to SFDC. I am trying to implement a clone functionality of a custom object  by which when I am cloning an object, the object as well as all the object in its related list are to be cloned.
I have implemented the part of cloning a object but stuck how to get the object list associated with a object's related list.
pls let me know , how to implement this.

Comment: This library might give you what you need, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child/8500#8500. If not you can study the code to figure out how to use Apex Describe to get the child relationship information. Sorry don't have time to do a full answer on this at present, but thought I'd post this in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the related list is already in memory you can clone it directly. For example:

```
List<Related_List_Object__c> relatedList = [SELECT Id, Field1__c, ... WHERE ParentId =: ...]
```

Then you can deepClone that list and save the results:

```
List<Related_List_Object__c> newList = relatedList.deepClone(false, false, false);
insert newList;
```

Details of [deepClone](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_System_List_deepClone.htm?SearchType=Stem) should help.