# How to clone child records on any object with url content using standard clone button

Tags: apex, visualforce, clone

i have tried to search a lot but not getting any solution for my problem. I would like to clone a parent object by clicking the standard clone button(Because all the fields are already prepopulated by standard clone button) and i would like to also clone the child records which are in the related list.

Many solutions are using the same logic [Deep Clone (Parent -> Child -> Grand Child)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child) i.e using deepclone or clone in the VF page. But using apex clone creates the records and we would like to keep it as in standard where the edit page is shown prepopulated and users can choose to change the details and save or cancel. I was thinking to put additional URL parameters which gives the source SFDC ID and which can be used in trigger to populate the child records. But clone URL always discard any additional url content at the time of save. Is there any way i can use button url logic to clone records?

Answer (score 0):

```
/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&cloneli=1&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&&CF00N1400000BBu7R=&00Na000000BA81u=&00N1400000BBk7c=&opp17=
```

I did this on the parent object page. It clones the related opportunity products

it's a custom button btw