# Cloning Opportunity record with child records with out using visualforce page

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, When I clone the opportunity record I should get the related record also (Example related record such as product record ) with out using visual force page .can someone please help me with this requirement

Comment: So you want to use the OOB Clone button on Opportunity Detail page and have it deep clone related records?  Note, if using Opportunity products, the OOB button gives option to clone those as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered multiple times across the forum and it was very well answered by Andrew you can go through this thread.

[Deep Clone in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child)