# Deep Clone Not Cloning the Child object

Tags: apex, visualforce

So basically what I need to do is clone an opportunity and all of it's field including the `OpportunityLineItem/Opportunity Product` if the `Opportunity` that I cloned has a `OpportunityLineItem` present

This is my code. Below you can see how I query them and clone them. Thank you in Advance, I badly needed this one.

```
public class LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt {

public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
public Opportunity newopp {get; set;}

public String opportunityID {get; set;}

public List<Opportunity> newOpportunity{get;set;}
public List<Opportunity> newOpportunityCloned;
public List<Opportunity> oldOpportunity;



public LPGVSPOpportunityCloneControllerExt (ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
newopp = (Opportunity)ctrl.getRecord();
opportunityID =(String)ctrl.getRecord().get('Id');
String query = 'SELECT ';
for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
    query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
}
query += 'Id FROM Opportunity where Id=: opportunityID ';
opp = (Opportunity)Database.query(query);
}
```

public List getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.LPG_SAP_Opportunity_Clone_Fields.getFields();
}

```
public PageReference DeepClone(){

Opportunity temp = opp.clone(false, True, false, false);
temp.RecordTypeID = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('LPG EU - VSP Opportunity').getRecordTypeId();
insert temp;





for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [Select OpportunityID from OpportunityLineItem where ID =: opp.ID]){
OpportunityLineItem oliNew = oli.clone(false,True,false,false);
insert oliNew;
}






PageReference NewOpportunity = new PageReference('/' + temp.id);
NewOpportunity.setRedirect(true);
return NewOpportunity;



}
```

}

The Opportunity is cloning perfectly fine but it is not cloning the `OpportunityLineItem` if the Opportunity That I cloned has a `OpportunityLineItem`

Comment: cloning `OpportunityLineItem` requires `pricebookentryId`, `unitPrice`, and `quantity` in addition to `opportunityId`

Comment: Have a look on this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child
You need to enrich your logic to extend it to children

Comment: @AmrIbrahim Can you please help me with this one. I tried them but it is not working because basically I used my field set that is why it's different. I'll post my whole code.

Comment: As @cropredy mentioned, you have to fill PricebookEntryId, OpportunityId, UnitPrice, Quantity, opportunityId and Product2Id to link those opportunity lineitems to the newly created opportunity

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar -- your list is correct except that `product2id` should not be included. SFDC will set it from the `pricebookentryid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're missing a line to assign opportunity line item to the opportunity.

```
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [Select OpportunityID from OpportunityLineItem where ID =: opp.ID]){ 
     OpportunityLineItem oliNew = oli.clone(false,True,false,false); 
     oliNew.OpportunityId = temp.Id;
     insert oliNew; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys it finally worked. I just added the missing line opportunity in the answer of @AmrIbrahim and Added the missing fields just like what @cropredy said and also chaging my where ID to Where OpportunityID.