# Cloning Parent -> Child -> Grand Child

Tags: apex, related-list, relationships, clone

I have one similar problem asked here. 
But My Objects are Project(Parent) -- > Milestone(Child) --> Action(GrandChild)..

[Deep Clone (Parent -> Child -> Grand Child)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child/8502)

I have tried using the External Id. But I am not sure how I will access Milestone.

This line of code..

`newOpp.Account = new Account(ExternalId__c = accNew.ExternalId__c); //set parent ref`

Here is the referencing  Account, how can I do this for custom relations. How I can reference object instead of Id.

```
Project__c proj = new Project__c(ExternalId__c = newProj.ExternalId__c);
// when crating milestone
newMileStone.Project__c = proj;   // when i tried this, it says i have to pass id instead of project.
```

If any one has done this before, I would like to get some inputs.

I have also tried @Avidev9's code. 
From that piece of code, there is something I couldn't understand completely. After inserting `newOpportunityList`, maps values are becoming null somehow. Tried debugging a lot. But no luck reaching the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the "reference" object instead ("__r"):

```
newMileStone.Project__r = proj;
```

Make sure the object you're setting *only* has one field enabled, and it is an external Id field (as in your sample code).