# Clone Opportunity through Salesforce REST API

Tags: rest-api, clone

I can see there was a standard functionality introduced by Salesforce to Clone and Clone with related for Opportunities, Therefore should be an endpoint available for this need, but I couldn't able to find this in any of the document. Is there any REST API endpoint available to clone an Opportunity by passing just the existing Opportunity Id/ with the updated request payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the moment there is no such standard REST API.
Here is a [Clone API Call](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqWV) idea, but it is almost dead.

You can build your own REST API resource, using your own custom Apex clone code, or take a look at the [Deep Clone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child) question here