# Can I deep clone a record but set the ID?

Tags: apex, loop, clone

I have two account records. I want to move all of the data from account #1 into account #2. Is it possible to do a deep clone and set the ID? Or would I have to loop through account #1 and pull the data from each field and push it into account #2?

Here is some code that might help clarify what I am looking to do:

```
    //OLD Account record
    Account accountMergeOLD = [SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Id = '999999999999999'];
    //NEW Account record
    Account accountMergeNEW = [SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Id = '333333333333333'];

    //we want to merge them 
    accountMergeNEW = accountMergeOLD.clone(false, true, false, true);
```

**Note:** I know that SOQL doesn't support the * selector, I just put it in to display the need for all fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep Clone (Parent -> Child -> Grand Child)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/deep-clone-parent-child-grand-child)

Comment: no it does not. This is not saving the data from one record into a second already existing record. This solution is creating a new account and saving the old account id into a custom field. I want to take the data from one existing account and push it into another existing account.

Comment: Why do you need to make account 2 identical to account 1 (including the name)?  Won't that cause duplicate issues?

Comment: I know it's an odd business requirement but we basically need to create duplicates with the exception of one field that will be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to move the data between existing accounts from Account1 to Account2, use clone() on Account1 to get all the data and then use merge on Account2 and cloned account.

clone() : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone

merge : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm

Comment: how would I save this into account #2?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! this will work for my requirements. I will mark your answer correct. I have a followup question - if I wanted to pick out one specific field to **not** clone, is this also possible to do without a loop? For example, there is a custom field on account that has a unique ID. This ID is the only way we can tell the difference between the two records.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Currently, there is no option to skip partial fields during clone. You can assign partial fields a null value on the cloned object.

Comment: okay, thank you for all of your help!